# How to show $(\exists x)( \forall y)\varphi\rightarrow( \forall y)(\exists x)\varphi $ is logically valid

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> How to show $(\exists x)( \forall y)\varphi\rightarrow( \forall y)(\exists x)\varphi $ is logically valid

Here is my attempt:

Assume it's not logically valid. Then, there's an interpretation $\mathscr{M}$  for which it's not true. Hence, there's a sequence $\vec a$ in the domain $M$ of $\mathscr{M}$ such that **1)** $ \vec a$ satisfies $(\exists x)( \forall y)\varphi$ and **2)** $\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $( \forall y)(\exists x)\varphi$

**1)** $\vec a$ satisfies $(\exists x)( \forall y)\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $(\forall x)( \exists y)\neg\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $( \exists y)\neg\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ satisfies $( \forall y)\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ satisfies $\varphi$

**2)** $\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $( \forall y)(\exists x)\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $(\exists x)\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ satisfies $(\forall x)\neg\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ satisfies $\neg\varphi$

Since $\vec a$ satisfies both $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$, which is a contradiction, then the formula must be valid.

Is it correct to show it this way?

> Edit:
>   **1)** If $\vec a$ satisfies $(\exists x)( \forall y)\varphi$, i.e $\neg \forall x(\neg\forall y(\varphi))$, then we have $\vec a$ does not satisfy $\forall x(\neg\forall y(\varphi))$ . Then, there is at least one sequence $\vec a'$ differing from $\vec a$ in at most the ith component not satisfying $\neg\forall y(\varphi)$.  Then, that means  $\vec a'$ satisfies $( \forall y)\varphi$.
>   **2)** If $\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $( \forall y)(\exists x)\varphi$, i.e $( \forall y)\neg(\forall x)(\neg\varphi)$, then there is at least one sequence $\vec a''$ differing from $\vec a$ in at most the jth component not satisfying $\neg(\forall x)(\neg\varphi)$. Then, that means   $\vec a''$ satisfies  $(\forall x)\neg\varphi$.
>   Now, we have $\vec a'$ satisfies $( \forall y)\varphi$ and $\vec a''$ satisfies  $(\forall x)\neg\varphi$. Then,  there is at least one sequence $\vec a'''$ differing from $\vec a$ in at most the $i$th and $j$th component satisfying $\varphi$ and satisfying $\neg\varphi$, which is a contradiction, then the formula must be valid.

This is from the book, so I applied what's written in $2$ actually
[image]

Comment: You can see **Example 1.9.3**, page 37 of Christopher Leary & Lars Kristiansen, [A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA37) (2nd ed 2015).

Comment: It's very nice, but it uses a bit different convention from the one we use. Does mine still count, though? :)

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Perhaps I'm just confused by your conventions (I assume $\vec a$ is a global variable assignment?), but what you've written does not seem to make sense. For instance, $\vec a$ satisfying $\exists x \forall y \varphi$ does not imply $\vec a$ satisfies $\phi.$ It holds for *some* $x$ (and any $y$) so you need to change the variable assignment to assign the appropriate value to $x.$

Comment: See my edit where I explain why I did it this way @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @LeylaAlkan That's Mendelson, I assume? I don't see any resemblance between what's written in $2$ and what you wrote. (You're going to have to use the rule for quantifiers at some point...)

Comment: Yes, it's from Mendelson. So, how can I improve my solution?

Comment: For instance, you write "$\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $(\forall x)( \exists y)\neg\varphi$ $\iff$ $\vec a$ doesn't satisfy $( \exists y)\neg\varphi$" but that is not what rule 4 says.

Comment: If you want to use Mendelson, you have to mimick the proof linked above using M's style. $s$ satisfies $(\exists x)(\forall y) \varphi$ iff there is a $s'$ that differs from $s$ only in the value given to $x$ (i.e. $s'(z)=s(z)$, if $z \ne x$ and $s'(x)=b$ for some $b \in M$) such that $s'$ satisfies $(\forall y) \varphi$. And so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to use from item 4 the part that says the sequence differs in at most the $i$th component.

For instance, say you have a sequence $a$ satisfying a formula $\psi = \exists x\forall y(\varphi)$. Mendelson uses only the universal quantifier, then, actually, the above rendering of $\psi$ is only syntactic sugar for $\neg \forall x(\neg\forall y(\varphi))$.

For a sequence $a$ to satisfy $\psi$, it means that, by item 2,  $a$ does not satisfy $\forall x(\neg\forall y(\varphi))$.

For $a$ to not satifsy $\forall x(\neg\forall y(\varphi))$, by item 4, it means that there is at least one sequence $a'$ differing from $a$ in at most the $i$th component (in wich $i$ is the index of the variable $x$) not satisfying $\neg\forall y(\varphi)$.

---

As for your edit, what you can get is actually

1. A sequence $a'$ differing from $a$ in at most the $i$th position ($i$ being the index of $x$) satisfying $\forall y (\varphi)$.
2. A sequence $a''$ differing from $a$ in at most the $j$th position ($j$ being the index of $y$) satisfying $\forall x(\neg\varphi)$.

for $x$ and $y$ can be different variables.

To obtain a contradiction from this you can use item 4 (from Mendelson) to obtain another sequence, say $a'''$, differing from $a$ in at most the $i$th and $j$th position that will work for both 1. and 2. above.

Comment: But the equivalent of $\psi = (\exists x)(\forall y)\varphi$ is $\neg (\forall x)(\exists y)(\neg \varphi)$

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you please check my edit? I think I cannot use the same $\vec a'$ , but don't know how else to get a contradiction

Comment: @LeylaAlkan , sorry, my bad. Changed the order of quantifier and negation. Fixed.

Comment: I changed my edit according to your way, can you again check it to see if it's okay now? @Tarc

Comment: Yes, I think that will work, @LeylaAlkan. Maybe you can add that $a'''$ can be obtained from $a'$ by assigning to its $j$th position the value $a''(j)$, or, equivalently, from $a''$ by assigning to its $i$th position the value $a'(i)$.